# import module to testing file

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocha.js

My app works fine but I cannot import my isolated functions from utils.ts file into test file.
Error message: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` (screen lower)

I have racked my brains all day long, have seen many tutorials and docs but I havent discovered any solution.
I would like to resolve it so I wasn't mandatory to have open running console while programming. This is only vanilla JS + HTML + CSS, I don't prefer to use commands like `npm init`.

I also went through many stackoverflow questions like that, but nothing works me, I cannot for example add `type: module` into package.json, because it causes another errors in my app.

Please, could someone help me where can I make mistake?

index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>  
      <button id="startAppBtn">start</button>
      <div id="container" class="container">   
        <div id="pointsBox" class="pointsBox"></div>
      </div>

      <script type="module" src="index.js" defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import { InsertionSort } from "./insertionSort.js";

const algo = new InsertionSort();

const startAppBtn = document.getElementById("startAppBtn");

startAppBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('start app');
    algo.mainApp(); /* all app is executed here inside this method, it contains 
               around 300 lines, so i didn't attache all the code inside, i don't 
               think it is important. */
});
```

utils.js

```
import Point from './point.js'; // => here it fails, this import evaluates testing file as error

export function xxx() {
    new Point(i, value[0] + 1);
    return 'xxx';
}
```

util.test.js

```
var assert = require('assert');
var { xxx } = require('./utils'); // here I import method from utils

describe('Array', function () {    
  describe('#xxx', function () {
    it('import test', function () {
      const res = xxx();     // here it is used
      assert.equal('xxx', res);
    });
  });
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^28.0.3"    
  }
}
```

screen:
[image]

Comment: Please try to minimize your example. Remove everything that does not add to the problem. It is hard to find the solution if there are so many different files and tools. Why is there an HTML FIle. Ive never used jest with HTML is it a problem with that?

Comment: htho: I removed one useless test + several lines from index.html, but the rest of the code - I have no idea which parts can or cannot cause this problem. All files only have several lines here.

Comment: Also you dont need to import assert. Jest provides its own assertions.Please take a look at the documentation. At first it seems overwhelmig, but so are the capabilities of jest. It is actually well written.

Comment: I have read both docs - Jest nad Mocha. I haven't come across problem like this.

Comment: Here is the documentation for jests matchers (assertions): https://jestjs.io/docs/using-matchers complete reference: https://jestjs.io/docs/expect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Althogh there is a lot of stuff that might go wrong in your example (since there is so much stuff with many points of failure), I'll make a guess - because its fun.

I see your test Files use `require()` so these are CommonJS modules. Your actual code uses import/export, so these are ES Moules. You can't just mix them. Unless you configure jest to use babel to transpile your source to CommonJS modules this wont work.
The [jest documentation has all the commands](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-babel). Configuring babel to transpile for the current node version should be sufficient.

If you only use ES Modules in your Codebase, you can change your test code to also use ES Modules. Check your jest configuration as you might need to tell jest to use ES Modules instead of CommonJS.
[Support is still experimental but you might give it a shot](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I used require( ), because jest testing doesn't natively support import syntax. But unfortunatelly with import syntax it behaves identically, so this is not the cause.

Comment: I've added some links to the documentation. You should try the babel approach first.

Comment: @user8620575 I probably should have mentioned you so you see the added links. Does it help?

Comment: Yes, it resolved my problem. I followed all instructions in section Using Babel at this link (first of yours) and I am capable to run the tests now. So the problem was mixture of CommonJS and ES Modules.
https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-babel